# Error uploading files to box.com using javascript

Tags: box-api

I am trying to reproduce this example (exactly): http://developers.blog.box.com/2013/05/13/uploading-files-with-cors/

The file is being uploaded but i am getting an error on the response, so i cannot know if the file was properly uploaded.

The error i am getting is:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content. Origin https://.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Any idea about what i can do to fix the issue?

Thanks,

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: Did you email api@box.com and ask for CORS access? It's off by default.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is disabled by default for API keys. Please email API@box.com to have it enabled for your account.